# Error with type declaration

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier." I've checked for semicolons and I've included the relevant libraries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int n = 8;
double p[n] = {1.23, .97, .86, .77, .69, .65, .71, .50};
double pi[n] = {.74, .70, .66, .68, .65, .62, .60, .54};
double z[n] = {.25, .35, .45, .55, .65, .75, .85, .95};

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("ppilow.txt"); //Error here
```

Comment: Im not even going to bother telling you what is the duplicate question, google it at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `myfile.open("ppilow.txt");` with following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  myfile.open("ppilow.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

Explanation: you can't put instructions outside body of functions.

But it is much better to avoid declaration of global variables, so I recommend you to move it into body too.